# Ionic V2 creating a prompt alert

Tags: ionic2

Here's my code:

```
public add() {
      let alert = Alert.create({
          title: "Add Date & Time",
          message: "Enter the date and time of your donation.",
          inputs: [
              {
                  name: "date",
                  placeholder: "DD/MM/YYYY"
              },
              {
                  name: "time",
                  placeholder: "HH:MM AM/PM"
              }
          ],
          buttons: [
              {
                  text: "Cancel"
              },
              {
                  text: "Save",
                  handler: data => {
                      this.donationHistoryList.push({
                          date: data.date,
                          time: data.time
                      });
                  }
              }
          ]
      });
      this.navCtrl.present(alert);
  }
```

Here are the errors I am getting

> Property 'create' does not exist on 'type of Alert'.

And

> Property 'present' does not exist on 'type of 'NavController'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
import {AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
```

In your constructor fn

```
constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

public add() { 
let alert = alertCtrl.create({ 
title: "Add Date & Time", 
message: "Enter the date and time of your donation.", 
inputs: [ { name: "date", placeholder: "DD/MM/YYYY" }, { name: "time", placeholder: "HH:MM AM/PM" } ],
buttons: [ { text: "Cancel" }, { text: "Save", handler: data => { this.donationHistoryList.push({ date: data.date, time: data.time }); } }] 
});
alert.present(); }
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now it's saying 'alertCtrl' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just add (this before alertCtrl variable).

```
this.alertCtrl.create(...)
```

Comment: Oops is before alertCtrl not after

Comment: please correct your own post if you feel you made a mistake.